# How do I hide an element when the escape key is pressed?

Tags: jquery

I found the following script for creating an overlay that opens in it another page:

```
<script>
    $("a#selector").live("click", function(){
        $(".overlayInner").load("logwork_form.php",
        // the following is the callback   
        function(){$(".overlayOuter").fadeIn(300); });
    });
</script>
```

I'd like to ask you to help me with adding some extra functionality to the script: closing the overlay on pressing the esc key.

I've tried adding the below code but it doesn't work.

```
//close if esc key is pres
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $(".overlayInner").close("logwork_form.php?proiect_id=13", function({
            $(".overlayOuter").fadeOut(300); 
});
```

Comment: Please stop using `.live()`, it's been deprecated for ages now. Use `.on()` (jQuery 1.7+) or `.delegate()` instead. More to the point of your question, what is the `.close()` method? Where is it defined?

Comment: the close method it isn't defined because I don't know hot to .... i know very little about jquery ...

Comment: What are you expecting the `.close()` method to do? Why do you pass a URL to it? Also, a good place to start might be fixing the various syntax errors (missing closing braces, parentheses in the wrong place).

Comment: the `close()` method was expected to hide the outerlayer. all the code is used to bring upfront a form to store some data in db.

Comment: also code you please make an example on how should the above function be modified to use `.on()` because I've tried to modify `$("a#selector").on("click", function(){ ..}` and it doesn't work any more

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since "close()" is not defined and there was a bracket missing...

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 27) {
        $(".overlayInner").fadeOut(300); 
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks it worked perfectly. i've done a little modification but the ideea was great
     $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            $(".overlayOuter").fadeOut(300); 
        }
      });

Comment: using `e.which` with jQuery is more cross-browser friendly

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to get key code and then put an if block for escape key code

```
   var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
```

above line works on all major browsers.

Comment: jQuery normalizes [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) so you can just use that.